# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 , flutter ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**im using mac with m1 chip.**

my project run on simulator perfectly while running with **Runner.xcodeproj** ,
but while running with **Runner.xcworkspace** it throws below error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "OBJC_CLASS$_CSToastStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FluttertoastPlugin.o
  "_CSToastPositionTop", referenced from:
      -[FluttertoastPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in FluttertoastPlugin.o
  "_CSToastPositionCenter", referenced from:
      -[FluttertoastPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in FluttertoastPlugin.o
  "_CSToastPositionBottom", referenced from:
      -[FluttertoastPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in FluttertoastPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

tried:
removing pod files, pod.lock,pod and reinstall.

```
flutter clean; rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock; rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace; flutter run
```

imported ios file from new project also didnt worked.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered same error,
here is the steps to solve this error

1. open Runner.xcworkspace in xcode,
2. goto pods project
3. goto build setting -> build architecture

   and change every build architecture for debug scheme to "Yes"

[image]

Comment: build active Architure only is already set to NO except debug, and im still getting this error.